# Clipped Scrollbar and Border in Webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit, textarea, scrollbar

Part of the textarea scrollbar and border is cut off:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Clipped Scrollbar and Border in Webkit</title>
    <style>
        textarea,
        iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        textarea {
            height: 200px;
            resize: none;
            outline: 0;
            border: solid red;
            border-width: 0 0 5px;
        }
        iframe {
            height: 0;
            border: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <textarea>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
        <p>Hello, world!</p>
    </textarea>
    <iframe srcdoc="<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/hpf5W/)**</kbd>

Why does it happen? What's the fix?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Given the fact that you have set your `iframe's` `height:0`, you can just set its `opacity` to `0`, but leave `display:block` and `srcdoc`.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hpf5W/5/)

```
textarea {

    display:block;
    width:300px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

iframe {

    opacity:0;
    height:0;
    border:0;

}
```

Comment: I need to use them with `display:block`. In addition, it causes a strange artifact on the right/bottom of the textarea in your demo.

Comment: I need the `srcdoc` attribute, too.